# Как сохранить картинку из ресурсов android приложения?

Tags: java, android

Вот что есть

```
Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.image);
String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
OutputStream out = null;
File file = new File(path, "imagename.png"); 

try {
    out = new FileOutputStream(file);
    bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out); 
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    try {
        if (out != null) {
            out.close();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Но есть проблема, у меня на телефоне без sd карты не работает. как можно исправить?

Answer (score 4):

Вот здесь:

```
String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
```

Вы получаете путь до sd-карты и зачем-то преобразуете его в строку.
А вот здесь:

```
File file = new File(path, "imagename.png");
```

Вы создаете файл (объект) "imagename.png" в папке, путь до которой лежит в `path`.

Работа с сохранением файлов:

Вот пример из [официальной документации](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html?hl=ru):

```
File file = new File(context.getFilesDir(), "imagename.png");
// дальше делаете то же самое
```

Более подробно:

```
File sdCardFolder = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(); // sd-карта
File projectFilesFolder = context.getFilesDir(); // внутренняя директория приложения

File file = new File(/* папка, в которой будет файл */, /* имя самого файла*/);
```

Comment: А какой путь нужно написать чтобы сохранить в память телефона в папку "загрузки"?

Comment: @Vladoo7 вы не сможете сохранить файл туда.